# Dart/Flutter Isolates - communication with Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I have a _downloadInIsolate(List args) function that works in an isolate. I call it from the VideoDownloadScreen widget. In this widget, after the code responsible for creating and communicating with the isolate, I have the following code:

```
      _receivePort.close();
      _isolate.kill();
      if (_progress == 100.0) {
        Provider.of<AppStateManager>(context, listen: false)
            .completeDownloadingAssets(true);
      } else {
        Provider.of<AppStateManager>(context, listen: false)
            .completeDownloadingAssets(false);
      }
```

Works well, but the user can close the widget and then this code will never execute (_downloadInIsolate() still working of course, but the user has no information that the download is finished). I use information about whether assets have been downloaded in several widgets, so I need the Provider.

I only found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69993917/19166990). Is this the only solution? Creating ReceivePort in AppStateManager (in my case) and registering it with IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName? And then in the isolate find port with IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName and send a download completion message?
Do you have any other suggestions?

What about killing the isolate at the end of the process?

Comment: What about placing this code in the dispose method as well?

Comment: @LuisUtrera, thanks for your answer. This code executes only after finishing downloading (or on an error). If I place it in the dispose method, if the user leaves the widget, the download process will stop. OK, maybe I didn't make it very clear, but that's why I used an isolate so that the download process will also continue after the user navigates to other widgets.